# update automatically a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cartesian-product

i have this question... i work on phpmyadmin and i have two tables(users and quests) each with their unique id! now i created another table as a relationship to the two like who has taken which quest???? i have the unique id's of the two tables and a flag wich shows 0-1 !!!

the question is...is there any possible way to make it as each time I update either table of the two mains the third(relashionship) will be updated as well???

in the third one i have the cartesian product of the unique id's combined with a flag( default 0 ). so i would like it to be autommated the updating of the third!

#### Update for clarification:

The first table has registered users `(uid,password,username)`

The second has questions `quest (qid,body,opt1,opt2)`

The third shows which user has answered which question. So i need in the third table all users combined with all the quests(via their id!) what i want to do is when i add a new user or quest, the third table to be updated like the foillowing example:

If i have users `1,2,3` and quests `1,2,3` and at the third table the connections

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(2,3)
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,3)
```

and I want to add the user `4` I would like the third to be autommatically with the

```
(4,1)
(4,2)
(4,3)
```

Comment: There are a few ways to automatically update relationships, depending on your needs. (foreign key `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or via triggers). Can you please provide more detail on exactly the structure of the 3 tables, and what is to be updated in the 3rd and under what circumstances? Also, you may need to provide a sample set of rows from each, together with a sample of what the new table looks like after modifications to the others.

Comment: the first table has registered users(uid,password,username) the second has questions
quest(qid,body,opt1,opt2)
the third shows which user has answered which question! so i need in the third table all users combined with all the quests(via their id!)

what i want to do is when i add a new user or quest, the third table to be updated like the foillowing example:

if i have users 1,2,3 and quests 1,2,3 and at the third table the connections (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)(3,3) and i want to add the user 4 i would like the third to be autommatically with the (4,1),(4,2),(4,3)

Comment: That's much clearer. I've edited your question above to express your comment.

Comment: thanx my friend...thanx for your time and help!